# Overriding a CSS property in customizing existing styles

Tags: html, css, layout

this is a very basic question but I cannot find the answer. There is the following style (part of):

```css
.grid-narrow {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 1.62
  ...
}
```

I need to use this style but with a different value of grid-column-gap property. I could copy & rename and use it but that sounds stupid.
I assume there is a way to somehow re-define the property, "override" it?

I thought something like

```css
.wideGap {
  grid-column-gap: 1.62* 1.62*1.62;
}
```

and then using the style `<div class="grid-narrow wideGap">` but that does not work.

I was browsing through W3 and other sites to understand but failed so far.

Comment: `grid-column-gap` is not a valid property. Perhaps you mean [`column-gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-gap)?

Comment: @InSync The code is not mine and it works as it is. It seems to be valid: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-column-gap.php

Comment: See the note on the webpage you linked:
> This property was renamed to `column-gap` in CSS3.

Comment: @Wongjn Thanks, okay, though I assume this has no influence on the issue I'm having because the property works if I fiddle with it. I just do not know how to "override" it without duplicating the whole style.

Comment: Use your browser dev tools to see exactly what CSS is being applied. I doubt the browser likes 1.62*1.62*1.62 as a value. Learn about CSS calc at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: @AHaworth I do not really know, this is a front-end code written by a very experienced developer. I'm a backend dev with 0 web development experience who inherited the whole solution :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grid-column-gap is doing nothing (unless you have some pre-processing going on which we don't know about) and although modern browsers may well still recognise it, the CSS3 version is column-gap.

Neither will accept a plain 1.62 as a valid value so I don't think it was working as you say, unless it's been changed by something else.

These snippets add a unit to the 1.62, and just as a guess I've used em as the unit - but you may mean px (though .02 of a px is pretty invisible) or even vw etc.

Here is a snippet which shows a grid with 10 items in it, the first with just the .grid-narrow class and the second adds the wide class.

Note - in CSS the C stands for 'cascade' and those definitions which come after those having the same selectivity weight take will override those that come before (but watch for the selectivity and if you are doing much of this type of alteration read up about it - MDN is a reliable reference source).

Now, the other illegal value was the 1.62*1.62*1.62. Not only does it not have a unit specified, CSS will do (simple) calculations for you, but only by using the calc function. See the setting below for how it's done, adding in a unit at the same time.

```css
.grid-narrow {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 1.62em;
  column-gap: 1.62em;
  /* added just for demo */
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100px;
  background: pink;
}

.wideGap {
  grid-column-gap: calc(1em * (1.62 * 1.62 * 1.62));
  background: cyan;
}

.grid-narrow>div {
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-narrow">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="grid-narrow wideGap">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, currently these calculations using just 1.62 certainly work, though as a whole it is:   grid-column-gap: 1.62 * 1.62 * 1.62 * @base-size;  . When I change the numbers, the gaps do change

Comment: What browser are you using, and is any preprocessor in use? Neither the calculation nor the 1.62 plain work on Chrome Windows 10, the CSS value is invalid.

Comment: As I said, I'm a backend dev with virtually 0 web dev. experience. The whole solution uses Meteor framework, and the app runs fine on Chrome and Edge (have not tried others). I really do not know how to find out if there is a preprocessor, but I guess there must be if it works?

Comment: It may be worth using you browsers dev tools inspect facility to see what the actual CSS being applied is. Also perhaps tagging your question with meteor to hopefully attract someone who knows about its syntax.